# How can I create persistent server-side objects in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a website in Django to display the results of a calculation on a large csv file.  I have this function in my views.py:

```
def results(request, input=""):
     from calculations import calculate
     from calculations import datamanager
     data = datamanager();
     return render(request, template, {"res":calculate(data.data, data.cov_table, input)}
```

Unfortunately, because the input varies quite a bit I run calculate every time and caching will not decrease loading times that much.

However, datamanger's init() method takes a long time because it has to read two large csv files, so only running it once will save time.

***Is there a way to only load datamanager when the server starts up and just access it from within the view?***

I have tried creating an app out of the object but then I read that "There’s no such thing as an Application object" on the Django webpage.

I would also like to avoid creating a Database.  The csvs definitely could be a database, but the datamanager class does a reasonable amount of processing on init.  This is for finance, so the datamanager class loads a list of securities: [ISIN, Return, STD, Volume, dict(key: time, value: price)] and a table of correlations.

Comment: You can use one of the various [cache backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/) to persist values.

Comment: Oh, would something like [local memory cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) be able to hold it?  I wasn't sure what that meant, this is my first time using Django.

Comment: It depends on your environment. If you are using a multi-process deployment environment, no, local memory would be duplicated among separate processes and a file or database backed engine would be more suitable. Alternatively you can use a  memory based persistence engine such as memcached or redis. If you are running a single Python process you can safely use the local memory. You should also consider the size of the data you are planning to store (obviously your local memory can't hold terabytes of data).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.